# How to make creepers scared of the player?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to make creepers scared of the player. The problem is, creepers don't seem to be scared of cats anymore. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible to do with commands.
It is possible to edit mob behavior using data-packs, though for any major AI changes, modding is typically the best answer.
For context through modding (and likely datapacks as well but I have less experience there) you can add players to the list of entities creepers are afraid of. Using commands you cannot change intrinsic properties of mobs, with the only mob AI related command's only capabilities being the total disabling of the mob's AI. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks! can you link a tutorial to make a datapack like that?

Answer (score 0):

This is including cats but not how creepers are afraid of cats, its how cats are scared of players.

All of the commands below need to be in repeating, always active command blocks:

```
/execute at @e[type=cat, name=creeper_scared] run tp @e[type=creeper, limit=1] ~ ~ ~
```

Command to type in chat:

```
/give @p creeper_spawn_egg{EntityTag:{id:"minecraft:cat",CatType:2,CustomName:"\"creeper_scared\"",CustomNameVisible:1,ActiveEffects:[{Id:14,Amplifier:0,Duration:2147483647}]}}
```

Then summon a creeper and that should work.

Also maybe do `/gamerule commandblockoutput false`